# Making a sketchup measurement plugin with ruby api

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I want to make a sketchup extension plugin where it will show length,width,height and area in a webdialog from the model file in sketchup .Then i want to pass the data to a third party Api. Any references how can i develop this plugin in ruby.I have some basics with ruby.I also looked into sketchup ruby offical documentation.Now i want some reference code to this kind of similar work which i can follow.

Comment: SketchUp's official github has an example project for "ruby - to - C" communication.  That may be what your are looking for: https://github.com/SketchUp/ruby-c-extension-examples